# Can't show the key along with the value (dict) in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am currently making a program where you have to find the averages of some kids' tests, and then print them along with the highest average.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def thetests():
    test1 = {'chris':93, 'john':90}
    test2 = {'chris':95, 'john':95}
    test3 = {'chris':91, 'john':88}
    return test1,test2,test3

def updatetests(test1,test2,test3):
    test1_1 = {'oscar':95, 'kevin':94, 'matthew':93, 'christine':90, 'anna':90}
    test2_1 = {'oscar':94, 'kevin':93, 'matthew':98, 'christine':95, 'anna':93}
    test3_1 = {'oscar':89, 'kevin':95, 'matthew':87, 'christine':91, 'anna':93}
    test1.update(test1_1)
    test2.update(test2_1)
    test3.update(test3_1)
    return test1,test2,test3


def findavg(test1,test2,test3):
    chris = (test1['chris']+test2['chris']+test3['chris'])/3
    john = (test1['john']+test2['john']+test3['john'])/3
    oscar = (test1['oscar']+test2['oscar']+test3['oscar'])/3
    kevin = (test1['kevin']+test2['kevin']+test3['kevin'])/3
    matthew = (test1['matthew']+test2['matthew']+test3['matthew'])/3
    anna = (test1['anna']+test2['anna']+test3['anna'])/3
    christine = (test1['christine']+test2['christine']+test3['christine'])/3

    print("chris,","%.2f" % chris)
    print("john,","%.2f" % john)
    print("oscar,","%.2f" % oscar)
    print("kevin,","%.2f" % kevin)
    print("matthew,","%.2f" % matthew)
    print("anna,","%.2f" % anna)
    print("christine,","%.2f" % christine)
    return chris,john,oscar,kevin,matthew,anna,christine

def maxavg(chris,john,oscar,kevin,matthew,anna,christine):
    value1 = chris
    value2 = john
    value3 = oscar
    value4 = kevin
    value5 = matthew
    value6 = anna
    value7 = christine
    if value1 > value2:
        maximum = value1
    elif value2 > value1:
        maximum = value2
        if value3 > maximum:
            maximum = value3
        elif value4 > maximum:
            maximum = value4
        elif value5 > maximum:
            maximum = value5
        elif value6 > maximum:
            maximum = value6
        else:
            maximum = value7

    print("The highest average is:", maximum)

def main():
    x,y,z = thetests()
    x,y,z = updatetests(x,y,z)
    a,b,c,d,e,f,g = findavg(x,y,z)
    maxavg(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)

main()
```

When run, the following comes up:

```
chris, 93.00
john, 91.00
oscar, 92.67
kevin, 94.00
matthew, 92.67
anna, 92.00
christine, 92.00
The highest average is: 93.0
```

It does give me the highest avg, however I want to print the name of the person along with the number, like this:

```
(name) has the highest average, which is: (percentage)
```

I don't want to use any imports.

**CODE UPDATE**

```
def thetests():
    test1 = {'chris':93, 'john':90}
    test2 = {'chris':95, 'john':95}
    test3 = {'chris':91, 'john':88}
    return test1,test2,test3

def updatetests(test1,test2,test3):
    test1_1 = {'oscar':95, 'kevin':94, 'matt':93, 'christine':90, 'anna':90}
    test2_1 = {'oscar':94, 'kevin':93, 'matt':98, 'christine':95, 'anna':93}
    test3_1 = {'oscar':89, 'kevin':95, 'matt':87, 'christine':91, 'anna':93}
    test1.update(test1_1)
    test2.update(test2_1)
    test3.update(test3_1)
    return test1,test2,test3


def findavg(test1,test2,test3):
    chris = {'name': 'chris', 'avg': (test1['chris']+test2['chris']+test3['chris'])/3}
    john  = {'name': 'john', 'avg': (test1['john']+test2['john']+test3['john'])/3}
    oscar = {'name': 'oscar', 'avg': (test1['oscar']+test2['oscar']+test3['oscar'])/3}
    kevin = {'name': 'kevin', 'avg':(test1['kevin']+test2['kevin']+test3['kevin'])/3}
    matt  = {'name': 'matt', 'avg': (test1['matt']+test2['matt']+test3['matt'])/3}
    anna  = {'name': 'anna', 'avg': (test1['anna']+test2['anna']+test3['anna'])/3}
    christine = {'name': 'christine', 'avg': (test1['christine']+test2['christine']+test3['christine'])/3}    
    print("chris,",chris['avg'])
    print("john,",john['avg'])
    print("oscar,",oscar['avg'])
    print("kevin,",kevin['avg'])
    print("matt,",matt['avg'])
    print("anna,",anna['avg'])
    print("christine,", christine['avg'])
    return chris,john,oscar,kevin,matt,anna,christine

def maxavg(chris,john,oscar,kevin,matt,anna,christine):
    value1 = chris['avg']
    value2 = john['avg']
    value3 = oscar['avg']
    value4 = kevin['avg']
    value5 = matt['avg']
    value6 = anna['avg']
    value7 = christine['avg']
    if value1 > value2:
        maximum = value1
    elif value2 > value1:
        maximum = value2
        if value3 > maximum:
            maximum = value3
        elif value4 > maximum:
            maximum = value4
        elif value5 > maximum:
            maximum = value5
        elif value6 > maximum:
            maximum = value6
        else:
            maximum = value7

    print("The maximum value is:", maximum)

def main():
    x,y,z = thetests()
    x,y,z = updatetests(x,y,z)
    a,b,c,d,e,f,g = findavg(x,y,z)
    maxavg(a,b,c,d,e,f,g)

main()
```

Any help is **GREATLY** appreciated.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use imports, unless this is an assignment?  In that case, just be honest ("it's an assignment so I can't use imports").

Comment: Correct. @SethMMorton

Comment: However `statistics` is ok

Comment: I noticed that statistics can just make the lines where I find the average, much much easier. But I don't feel like going back now. And to confirm, yes it's an assignment @SethMMorton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values that findavg() returns are not dicts, they're just integers, so they don't have the name data. You cannot print the name of the variable either, because of how python variables work.

I would suggest having findavg() return a dict or list or another data structure. For instance,

```
chris = {'name': 'chris', 'avg': (test1['chris']+test2['chris']+test3['chris'])/3}
```

Comment: I've tried doing this, but it doesn't work; see my code update.

Comment: Just do `chris = {'name': 'chris', 'avg': (test1['chris']+test2['chris']+test3['chris'])/3.0}` and format the numbers later. You're storing a string instead of a number in 'avg'.

Comment: updated. so now should I do the `%.2f` as before? in the same place?

Comment: Yes, use `print("%.2f" % chris['avg'])`.

Comment: Great it works. So how would I print the following: `(Name) got the highest average of (theaverage)`?

Comment: Something like `print("{} got the highest average of {}".format(chris['name'], "%.2f"%chris['avg']))`

Comment: won't that make it always be chris?

Comment: Yes, just change chris to john or whatever else the name of the dict is. In the future, look towards sticking your data into data structures. You could, for example, use *args or **kwargs in the maxavg function so you could use a for loop and not have to type things out over and over. edit: oh you mean that. Yeah, you could either store the dict in maximum or create another variable that holds that the name as a string.

Comment: `if value1 > value2: maximum = chris` and so on for the other conditional statements, and then when you print out the the final result, you do `print("{} got the highest average of {}".format(maximum['name'], "%.2f"%maximum['avg']))`. As to the other thing, *args and **kwargs take arbritary amounts of parameters and stores them a tuple and dict respectively. You can then use a for loop to iterate through them.